# Lower bound construction for the extremal number of $C_{2k}$-free bipartite graph

Tags: extremal-graph-theory

Suppose $G(V_1 \cup V_2, E)$ is a bipartite graph with parts $|V_1|=n$ and $|V_2|=m.$ What is the best known lower bound construction for the maximum number of edges in $G$ when $G$ does not have a cycle of length $8.$

I'm looking for some references.

Comment: If $N=m+n$ and there no restrictions on $m$ and $n$, the unique extremal graph for $N\le 63$ is $K_{3,N-3}$.  Clearly this doesn't continue forever, but when does the first exception occur?

Answer (score 2):

It's a major open question to determine this value, even up to constant factors, even when $n=m$.  In this special case, the best upper bound has the form $|E| = O(n^{1 + 1/4})$ (see [this paper](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maskat/Papers/EvenCycle.pdf) or many others), while the best lower bound has the form $|E| = \Omega(n^{1 + 1/5})$ (the only lower bound graph I'm aware of is the incidence graph of the Split Cayley Hexagon, but unfortunately I can't point you at a good reference for how to build this, and I don't know if there's a simpler construction out there.  Maybe someone can help me out here).

For the general case when $n < m$, it should be easy to extend the results of the above upper bound paper to prove $|E| = O(n^{3/4} m^{1/2} + m)$ (I did some back-of-the-envelope computations here but I haven't totally verified this, so beware).  The only interesting lower bound graph I'm aware of is the incidence graph of the twisted triality hexagon, which I believe requires $m = n^{5/4}$ and then gives $|E| = \Omega(n^{11/8})$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please give a reference for the twisted triality hexagon?

Comment: I'd go for the book "Generalized Polygons" by Maldeghem, pp114-116, if you're comfortable with the algebra: https://books.google.com/books?id=jBQHCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=twisted+triality+hexagon&source=bl&ots=FZWhiZ0oRd&sig=Efo4zbplIC-I6iD2Z0ZFDngk9Dk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjltsGzyurdAhWhVN8KHWkODDIQ6AEwBXoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=twisted%20triality%20hexagon&f=false

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_polygon for a more intro description of why these generalized polygon constructions are relevant to your question.